# Security .NET MVC C#, FormsAuthentication

Tags: .net, security

I am building one of my first MVC projects. 
Now I have come to the stage where I am developing the login!

I never used FormsAuthentication, and I am new to this.. 
But how "stupid"/insecure is it to do this if the user is valid:

```
 FormsAuthentication.Initialize();
 FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("NameOnCookie", false);
```

And then I do this, in the top of my controller:

```
[Authorize(Users = "NameOnCookie")]
```

Is it dumb, or is it a secure way to work?! 
If it is a wrong way to work, give me directions!

And if its insecure why? How can you crack it?

Thanks!

Comment: "NameOnCookie" being a specific username?

Comment: NameOnCoockie Just a name I set if the User is Valid or not, thats the thought.....

Answer (score 1):

The `Users` property of `AuthorizeAttribute` specifies which users are allowed to call your action, so if you're specifically wanting a user with the exact username "NameOnCookie" to be authorized, your solution will work (assuming that you only called `SetAuthCookie` after a proper authentication took place).